# Change height of Bootstrap Navbar to 85px and keep it aligned vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I'm having some trouble with my bootstrap navbar. I want the navbar to be 85px in height with the logo and li items centered vertically in the 85px. I can't seem it get it working right.

A good example of what I want is https://devmounta.in/ navbar

HTML:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="css/images/logo.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li id="item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li id="item"><a href="#">Stats</a></li>
        <li id="item"><a href="#">Drivers</a></li>
        <li id="item"><a href="#">Facts</a></li>
        <li id="btn"><a href="#">Pledge Now</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
header{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background-color: #66CCFF;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(102, 204, 255, .9);
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 10;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar-default {
 background: 0 0;
 border: none;
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.container-fluid {
 padding: 0;
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/xwthov5s/

```
header{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background-color: #66CCFF;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(102, 204, 255, .9);
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 10;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar-default {
 background: 0 0;
 border: none;
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.container-fluid {
 padding: 0;
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.navbar-nav{
    height:85px;
}
ul.navbar-nav li{
    line-height:85px;
}
.navbar-brand{
    display:block;
    height:85px;
    line-height:85px;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav li>a {
    color: #777;
    line-height: 85px;
    padding-top: 0;
    display:block;
    height:85px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to adjust the height of the `navbar` it's usually best to use padding that way your toggle button remains vertically centered with the `navbar-brand` as well once you're under 768px.

Alternatively the best way to do this is if you're using a pre-processor (SASS/LESS) as it takes only one CSS Rule to accomplish this. [Bootstrap-SASS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss) or [LESS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less)

*I also added custom classes to your `navbar` and the `container-fluid` class so you don't directly change the core CSS.

See working example in Snippet (Full Page).

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #66CCFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(102, 204, 255, .9);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*REMOVE - FOR HEADER*/
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  /*REMOVE - FOR HEADER*/
}
.navbar.navbar-custom {
  /*REMOVE - FOR HEADER*/
  margin-top: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  /*REMOVE - FOR HEADER*/
  background: 0 0;
  border: none;
  padding-top: 17.5px;
  padding-bottom: 17.5px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: -17.5px;
}
.navbar .container-fluid.container-nav {
  width: 90%;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-collapse {
    border: none;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header>I'm a Header</header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid container-nav">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x85">
      </a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li id="item"><a href="#">About</a>

        </li>
        <li id="item"><a href="#">Stats</a>

        </li>
        <li id="item"><a href="#">Drivers</a>

        </li>
        <li id="item"><a href="#">Facts</a>

        </li>
        <li id="btn"><a href="#">Pledge Now</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well">YUP</div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
    Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```